# How do we style webcomponents in the context of re-usability and sharing styles across components

Tags: css, angular, styling

I am trying to arrive at a strategy to add branding(style) to  web components (angular 2 components in my case).I want to arrive at a consensus where there is a possibility of same component repeating multiple times on a page. Want to avoid duplication while packaging styles across components and abstract it. How do i arrive at a solution when the style needs to be atomic to the component and when to abstract it and how do i need to go about it. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it's really useful to have several style files that handle specific areas. In my case I called those template. This is an example of my main.scss file in my main project:

```
@import 'templates/menu.scss';
@import 'templates/forms.scss';
@import 'templates/pagination.scss';
@import 'templates/general.scss';
@import 'templates/type.scss';
@import 'templates/labels.scss';
@import 'templates/navbar.scss';
@import 'templates/sidebar.scss';
@import 'templates/buttons.scss';
@import 'templates/tables.scss';
@import 'templates/panels.scss';
@import 'templates/alerts.scss';
@import 'templates/loading.scss';
@import 'templates/calendar.scss';
@import 'templates/comment-input.scss';
```

I've been created these on demand. It's like writing any kind of reusable code. When you or some one in your team notice that what is about to be created already exists. It's better to remove from the style of the component and place it on a style file that has larger scope.

We are in a team of 5 developers and it has been working really well. Components have their specific behavior isolated but the behaviors that they share are available to any component to use.

> Another approach that I've though about using is to only import the template files as another styleUrl in the component. This way I would guarantee even more the style encapsulation.

Let's say you have a component that have its specific behavior, but you also want it to have the labels.scss available to it. You would do this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.component.html'
  styleUrls: ['my-component.component.css', '../shared/styles/labels.css']
})
```

I really like this second approach, but as the project gets really big you can have some nasty relative paths to be handled when importing the shared styles.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks much. That helps!:)